# NET CORE - Get 500 instead of 401 when connection is slow

Tags: .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I've an API with Authentication to post a file on my server.

If I try to call API by posting a large file (10MB about) without authentication I got 401 as expected, but, if I try to call the same API with a slow internet connection, strangely I got 500 (internal server error).

Backend side, the only log I see is: the application completed without reading the entire request body.

So, is it possible get 401 even when the internet connection is slower than usual?

Any idea?

Comment: 500 means the server crashed, possibly due to a timeout. This probably means that a custom authentication middleware is waiting for the entire file to arrive before deciding whether to reject it or not. Without any code we can't guess what's happening. Authentication shouldn't depend on receiving the entire request before running. That's not only inefficient, it's a Denial-of-Service security risk as well. Someone could start posting huge files to the service to crash it

Comment: There is a simple auth engine: services.AddAuthentication(p => ... and .AddJwtBearer(authenticationScheme: "Bearer", p => ... so I don't know why authentication mechanism is waiting for the full request.